# Can the composite of two projections really fail to be a projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $H$ denote a Hilbert space. For any closed subspace $C \subseteq H$, write $P_C$ for the orthogonal projection onto $C$. Then [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthogonal_complements_and_projections), the composite $P_U \circ P_V$ needn't be a projection. That is, it needn't be the case that $P_U \circ P_V = P_{U \cap V}.$ Is this really true?

Comment: To clarify: is $P_C$ supposed to be orthogonal projection?  (If not, such a projection is not unique, so it doesn't really make sense to speak of "the" projection.)

Comment: @NateEldredge, I feel confused about the terminology. By $P_C$, I mean the linear transform $P_C : H \rightarrow H$ such that $\mathrm{img}(P_C) \subseteq C$ and such that $\| P_C(x) -x\| \leq \|y - x\|$ for all $y \in \mathrm{img}(P_C)$. Is that called the orthogonal projection onto $C$?

Comment: Yes, that is orthogonal projection.  You can verify that $P_C x - x$ is orthogonal to $C$.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thanks. It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true, which can be readily shown in ${\mathbb{R}^2}$.

Let $U = \left\{ {\left( {x,0} \right):x \in \mathbb{R}} \right\}$ and $V = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right):x - y = 0} \right\}$.

Let ${P_U}\left( {x,y} \right) = \left( {x + y,0} \right)$ and ${P_V}\left( {x,y} \right) = \left( {x,x} \right)$. Note that both are projections, since $P_U^2 = {P_U}$ and $P_V^2 = {P_V}$.

Then ${\left( {{P_V}{P_U}} \right)^2} \ne {P_V}{P_U}$, since ${P_U}\left( {1,1} \right) = \left( {2,0} \right),{P_V}\left( {2,0} \right) = \left( {2,2} \right),{P_U}\left( {2,2} \right) = \left( {4,0} \right),{P_V}\left( {4,0} \right) = \left( {4,4} \right)$, so ${{P_V}{P_U}}$ isn't a projection, although both ${P_V}$ and ${P_U}$ are.

EDIT: Note that the notions of projection and orthogonal projection are not the same. Definition of projection is that it is a linear map which is idempotent. Definition of orthogonal projection is that it is a projection whose image and kernel are orthogonal. It can be shown that the orthogonality condition is equivalent to the condition that ${P^*} = P$. So, for projections we have ${P^2} = P$, while for orthogonal projections we have ${P^2} = P = {P^*}$ (${P^*}$ is the adjoined map to $P$).

One can wonder, since the statement doesn't hold for projections in general, is it true if we restrict ourselves to orthogonal projections?

The answer remains no, since ${P_U}\left( {x,y} \right) = \left( {x,0} \right)$ and ${P_V}\left( {x,y} \right) = \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2},\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right)$ are orthogonal projections ($P_U^2 = {P_U}$, $P_V^2 = {P_V}$, $\operatorname{Im} {P_U} = \left\{ {\left( {x,0} \right):x \in \mathbb{R}} \right\} \bot \left\{ {\left( {0,y} \right):y \in \mathbb{R}} \right\} = \ker {P_U}$ and $\operatorname{Im} {P_V} = \left\{ {\left( {x,x} \right):x \in \mathbb{R}} \right\} \bot \left\{ {\left( { - x,x} \right):x \in \mathbb{R}} \right\} = \ker {P_V}$), but ${P_U}{P_V}{P_U}{P_V}\left( {1,1} \right) = {P_U}{P_V}{P_U}\left( {1,1} \right) = {P_U}{P_V}\left( {1,0} \right) = {P_U}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}} \right) = \left( {\frac{1}{2},0} \right)$, so ${P_U}{P_V}\left( {1,1} \right) = \left( {1,0} \right) \ne \left( {\frac{1}{2},0} \right) = {\left( {{P_U}{P_V}} \right)^2}\left( {1,1} \right)$.

We conclude that even orthogonality doesn't guarantee that ${{P_U}{P_V}}$ remains a projection, let alone an orthogonal projection.

Comment: What you call $P_U$ and $P_V$ are not the *orthogonal* projections onto subspaces $U$ and $V$. They do not respect the Hilbert space structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In the question the notation with $P$ was reserved for orthogonal projections. But with the same spaces $U$ and $V$ as above, one is a horizontal line through the origin (the $x$ axis), and the other one is a line at an angle of $\pi /4$ to the first one. Take the point $(x_0,y_0)=(2,0)$. If you project first onto $U$, you get $(2,0)$ again. If you project that to $V$, you get $(1,1)$. That is outside $U\cap V$ (which is $\{ 0\}$).

Comment: The question was about projections, not orthogonal projections

Comment: Further projecting $(1,1)$ onto $U$ gives $(1,0)$. We see that $(P_V \circ P_U) \circ (P_V \circ P_U) \ne (P_V \circ P_U)$ (just evaluate at $(2,0)$), so the composition is not idempotent. It also shows that $P_V \circ P_U \ne P_U \circ P_V$. The matrix representations can be found from $P_U(x,y)=(x,0)$ and $P_V(x,y)=((x+y)/2,(x+y)/2)$. ***Edit:*** Ah, after your edits you address this as well. Will upvote.